# Meteor Session.set() from mongodb property in helper function not working after deploy

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to set the session from a property in the mongodb. I have this working locally, but after deploy I get this error in the console, and a white screen of death.

> Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'siteTheme' of undefined

```
// helper
Handlebars.registerHelper("site", function(){
      host =  headers.get('host');
      theSite = Site.findOne({'domain': host});
      theme = theSite.siteTheme;  
      // Problem - Works locally, not deployed with mup.
      // Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot read property 'siteTheme' of undefined 
      Session.set("theme", theme); 

      return theSite;
});



// Add theme class to html

siteTheme0 = function(){
  $('html').addClass('theme0');
};
siteTheme1 = function(){
  $('html').addClass('theme1');
};
siteTheme2 = function(){
  $('html').addClass('theme2');
};
siteTheme3 = function(){
  $('html').addClass('theme3');
};


// Change theme on change to db

Deps.autorun(function (c) {

  if (Session.equals("theme", "1")){
    siteTheme1();
  }
  else if (Session.equals("theme", "2")){
    siteTheme2();
  }
  else if (Session.equals("theme", "3")){
    siteTheme3();
  }
  else {
    Session.set("theme", "0");
    siteTheme0();
  }
});
```

Comment: Open the mongo console and make sure that there is actually data there. If there is no data where `'domain':host`, nothing will be returned, which causes your error. To do this, open a terminal in your project directory and type in `meteor mongo` to access your mongo shell.

Comment: Unrelated but maybe worth pointing out that the `host`, `theSite`, and `theme` vars in your handlebars helper function will end up being global variables. Probably not good. You should prefix them with `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the most commonly encountered problems with meteor. Your collection data isn't ready when your helper is called (or it doesn't exist), so `Site.findOne` returns `undefined` and you can't access `siteTheme` of `undefined`. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942025/waiting-for-meteor-collection-to-finish-before-next-step). Basically you just need to add some kind of guard or return statement and assume the data may not be ready. For example:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("site", function(){
  var host = headers.get('host');
  var theSite = Site.findOne({'domain': host});
  if (theSite) {
    var theme = theSite.siteTheme;
    Session.set("theme", theme);
    return theSite;
  }
});
```

If the rest of your code is written properly, your template should render again as soon as the data is ready.

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing, the wait for the collection to be ready.