# Meteor - why can't I store my Meteor.subscribe handle in the Session? I need to get it later to stop the subscription

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I have the following code:

```js
sub_geo = Meteor.subscribe('geo');
console.log('sub_geo returned from Meteor.subscribe: ');
console.log(sub_geo);
Session.set('sub_geo', sub_geo);
console.log('sub_geo retrieved from Session: ');
console.log(Session.get('sub_geo'));
```

The output is as follows:

```js
sub_geo returned from Meteor.subscribe:
> Object {stop: function, ready: function}
sub_geo retrieved from Session:
> Object {}
```

Obviously I need to store the returned subscription handle because I need to call the `ready()` and `stop()` functions on it later.  Not sure how else to store it other than in the Session.  Can I just use a global variable?  Also - even if there is some other way of doing it, why doesn't this approach work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can only store EJSON-serializable objects in session variables. If you need the subscription handle outside of the current file, you'll need to store it in a global variable (perhaps under a namespace like `Subscriptions` - e.g. see richsilv's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376103/right-way-to-use-subscriptions-in-meteor).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this, but not the way you would expect.
Just set the Session as you do:

`Session.set('sub_geo', sub_geo);`

Then when you want to do something with your subscription, retrieve the handle from Meteor's own registry:

`const handle = Meteor.default_connection._subscriptions[Session.get('sub_geo').subscriptionId]`

And if you ARE going to use the Session (which is not encouraged, except if you really have to), clean it up:

`delete Session.keys['sub_geo'];`

This is working fine in Meteor 1.3.3.1 for me at the moment, but probably will work for most previous versions as well.

PS: Alternatives for Session are Reactive Var and Reactive Dict.