# (Meteor) #each failing with data from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, meteor

I'm making a test/quiz app with Meteor, and have all the questions, possible answers etc. stored in a local MongoDB like so:

```json
{
type: "someType",
skillType: "someSkillType",
questions: [ 
    {
    questionID: 1,
    question: "Some question",
    answer: 2,
    option1: "Some possible answer",
    option2: "Another one",
    option3: "Etc."
    },
    {
    questionID: 2,
    question: "Some question 2",
    answer: 1,
    option1: "Some possible answer",
    option2: "Another one",
    option3: "Etc."
    }
    ]
}
```

And so on. I've tested and made absolutely sure that it's not my `Meteor.Collection`, `Meteor.publish / Meteor.subscribe` or the connection to the database that is the problem. The data is there, and I can access it from the console just fine.

My template looks like this:

```
<template name="test">
    <form name="testForm" id="testForm" role="form">
        {{#each testQuestions}}
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <p><b>{{questionID}}.</b> {{question}}</p>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="qNumber{{questionID}}" value="1" required>
                                {{option1}}
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="qNumber{{questionID}}" value="2">
                                {{option2}}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="qNumber{{questionID}}" value="3">
                                {{option3}}
                        </label>
                    </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </form>
</template>
```

I've then made a template helper to get the data:

```js
Template.test.testQuestions = function () {
    questionsAll = allQuestions.findOne({"type": "someType", "skillType": "someSkillType"}, {fields: {"_id": 0, "type": 0, "skillType": 0, "questions.answer": 0 }});
    questionsAll1 = EJSON.toJSONValue((questionsAll.questions)); // I've tried both with and without this part.
    return questionsAll1;
}
```

It doesn't work however, nothing gets rendered and I get a very long error in the console, starting with:

```
"Exception from Deps recompute function: .observeChanges@.......
```

If I make a static array directly in the template helper, it works fine however. I feel like I've tried everything, and I simply cannot figure out the cause. Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a situation where you need to add guards because the `findOne` could return `undefined` before the subscription is ready. You can do:

```
Template.test.testQuestions = function() {
  var aq = allQuestions.findOne({
    type: 'someType',
    skillType: 'someSkillType'
  });

  if (aq && aq.questions) {
    return aq.questions;
  }
};
```

You don't need to convert anything with `EJSON.toJSONValue`. Also note that `qid` doesn't seem to exist in your sample data. Maybe you mean `questionID`?

Comment: Yes, I meant `questionID` instead of `qid` - thanks for pointing that out :) That was a mistake in the data example.

I just tried out your suggestion as well, and no dice unfortunately. I still get the same (huge) error.

Comment: That's... Amazing. It works! Not that it really makes sense to me that the `if` statement should make a difference, but apparently it does. I'd give you all the reputation in the world if I could - I've been scratching my head like crazy over this one. Thanks again!

Comment: Great - I'm glad we got it working! For more info I'd also recommend looking at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942025/waiting-for-meteor-collection-to-finish-before-next-step). The short version is that it takes a non-zero amount of time to get the subscription data to the client. If the template renders before the data is ready, you have to allow for that with a guard. This is a common issue when working with meteor and I'm hopeful that the docs for 1.0 will address this more clearly.

Comment: Yeah, can't believe you found a solution so fast. I'd been trying for days to figure it out. Regarding the question you linked to (which I hadn't seen before).. Well, it's strange because I actually am using iron-router and `waitOn: function () { return Meteor.subscribe('example') }` for all non global subscriptions. Still wasn't working till I used your solution however.