# Weird behavior of fetch()

Tags: meteor

While integrating Meteor typeahead library, I ran into something weird. Refer to the code below

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.registerHelper("course_data", function() {
    return [
      {
        name: 'course-info1',
        valueKey: 'titleLong',
        local: function() { 
          return Courses.find().fetch();
        },
        template: 'Course'
      },
      {
        name: 'course-info2',
        valueKey: 'catalog',
        local: function() { 
          return Courses.find().fetch();
        },
        template: 'Course'
      },
      {
        name: 'course-info3',
        valueKey: 'catalogNbr',
        local: function() { 
          return Courses.find().fetch();
        },
        template: 'Course'
      }
```

This worked great but I found the website was suffering from overhead. I thought a part of the cause relied on the code above, because I am calling `fetch()` three times unnecessarily to get the same objects. Therefore, I replaced each `Courses.find().fetch()` with just `courses`.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.registerHelper("course_data", function() {
    var courses = Courses.find().fetch();
    return [
      {
        name: 'course-info1',
        valueKey: 'titleLong',
        local: function() { 
          return courses;
        },
        template: 'Course'
      },
      {
        name: 'course-info2',
        valueKey: 'catalog',
        local: function() { 
          return courses;
        },
        template: 'Course'
      },
      {
        name: 'course-info3',
        valueKey: 'catalogNbr',
        local: function() { 
          return courses;
        },
        template: 'Course'
      }
```

I thought it's virtually the same code but it doesn't work anymore. The objects do not seem to be fetched correctly. Is there anything that I am missing here?

*possibly related: [Waiting for meteor collection to finish before next step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942025/waiting-for-meteor-collection-to-finish-before-next-step)*

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
local: courses,
```

instead of:

```
local: function() { 
    return courses;
},
```

Probably the return of a function instead of value is interfering with the reactive evaluation mechanism.